# sql login does not map to a user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Using SQL management studio, I deleted my existing database (since for some reason I could not restore it otherwise) and restored the DB from a backup.

after deleting the db, the login associated with the user of that db has lost its connection (no default database and no mapping).

I choose the default database to the restored db, while trying to map the login to the user I get an error:

> Error Number: 15023 
>   User, group, or role 'myUser-LoginName' already
>   exists in the current database. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

while attemting to fix orphand users with the following query:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'UPDATE_ONE','myUser-LoginName','myUser-LoginName'
```

I get the result:

> Msg 15291, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_change_users_login, Line
>   114 Terminating this procedure. The User name 'myUser-LoginName' is
>   absent or invalid.

just to clarify my login and user have the same name.

how can I fix this annoying problem? please.

Comment: Can you run `EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report'` and see whether there are users who are not linked to a login?

Comment: @visakh the result is: 
myUser-LoginName 0x0C36CE0E39CD274885E707BF604B57BA

Comment: Can you run these two queries and see whether the `sids` are different?

`select name,sid  from master.sys.server_principals where name = your_username;`
`select  name,sid  from sys.database_principals where name = your_username;`

Comment: the second query you posted gave the same UserSID while the first result a different sid. can you tell anything from this results?

Comment: It seems like you have run into the problem of 'Orphaned' users. Try running this - `EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix','[UserName]','[LoginName]'` . You need full admin rights to run this. If this doesn't fix the issue, then unfortunately, I can't help much.

Comment: @visakh this is the result:
`Msg 15600, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_change_users_login, Line 181
An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure 'sys.sp_change_users_login'.`

Comment: Can you take a look at this?(http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2009/12/invalid-parameter-or-option-was.html)